Prometheus Scrape Interval Causing Time Difference in Metrics Monitoring
Timing is a crucial component in our business, so I have to have a robust monitoring of our servers' time. For this purpose, I have set up the prometheus node-exporter in our servers to get the servers' time from the node_time_seconds metric.
There's an external source with which our servers' time should be synched (i.e. timeanddate.com) and I deployed an app to get the time reported by that source in Unix epoch format via an API when calling this domain: http://time-exporter.mydomain.local/metrics.
Considering the following metrics:
servers' time reported by node_time_seconds metric of the node-exporter job: node_time_seconds 1.7223269513417892e+09
external reference time reported by timeanddate_current_time_seconds metric of the time-exporter job: timeanddate_current_time_seconds 1722326859
the solution seems easy: by subtracting node_time_seconds metric from timeanddate_current_time_seconds, I get the difference between the time reported by the servers and the time reported by the external reference (i.e. node_time_seconds - timeanddate_xurrent_time), and if this value is greater than 1 (second), prometheus' alert manager send me an alert.
But the problem I'm facing here is by considering the prometheus' scrape_interval of 120 seconds, when I subtract these two metrics and get the time difference, it returns me values ranging from 0 to 120 for each instance (server). This is because of the difference in times when the prometheus scraped the node-exporter job and time-exporter job within the scraped interval. For example, prometheus scraped the node-exporter in the 20th second and scraped the time-exporter in the 100th second of the scrape interval. Both return the correct time of when they've been scraped, but the subtraction of the metrics gives me a value of 80, and is not near to zero.
The query I'm using to get the time difference is as follows:
abs (last_over_time(node_time_seconds [2m]) - ignoring (instance,job) group_left last_over_time(timeanddate_current_time_seconds[2m]))

Note that because of the difference in the instance and job names, and many-to-one query structure, I'm using ignoring and group_left functions. Also using the last_over_time function to get the most recent point values.
As ChatGPT suggests, I've also tried the following query:
abs ( abs(node_time_seconds - timestamp(node_time_seconds)) - ignoring (instance,job) group_left abs(timeanddate_current_time_seconds - timestamp(timeanddate_current_time_seconds)))

Although it returns me a value below 1 second, it doesn't make sense either, since the time_stamp function returns the time when the sample scraped based on the prometheus server time and it may not be exact.
I want to know if there's a way to ensure Prometheus scrapes both metrics at the same time or aligns their scrapes better.
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!
P.S

I'm using Debian 12 OS with Chrony to maintain time synchronization in our servers, but need to check its validity via an external reference I mentioned above. Also the prometheus version I'm using is 2.45.4.
Your answers/helps can be not only limited to prometheus. What alternatives or best practices can I use to accurately monitor and alert on time synchronization? For example, I'm getting both metrics with this command at the same time and their manual subtraction gives me a near to zero value:
curl -s http://time-exporter.mydomain.local/metrics | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $2}' && curl -s http://<some_ip>:9100/metrics | grep "^node_time_seconds" | awk '{print $2}'


Prometheus doesn't provide the ability to align scrapes for distinct targets at the same time. The solution is to set up the reference time on the server where Prometheus runs. Then Prometheus will store the reference time as metric timestamp during scraping, so you can use the following PromQL query for alerting on time discrepancies bigger than one second at scrape targets:
abs(timestamp(node_time_seconds) - node_time_seconds) > 1

See timestamp() docs.
P.S. you can use an alternative Prometheus-like monitoring solution I work on - VictoriaMetrics and/or vmagent. It supports aligning of scrape timings for different targets via scrape_align_interval option in scrape configs - see these docs. Note that single-node VictoriaMetrics is able to scrape targets without vmagent - see these docs.
